# I have the following error in Telegraf when sending data from influxdb to mqt

Tags: python, mqtt, flux, telegraf, influxdb-2

I am a beginner in `telegraf` and `infux db`, and I am trying to send information from a cube, but I get the following error.

E! error loading config file plugin `inputs.influxdb`:

```
line 79: configuration specified the fields [“token” “org” “bucket”],
```

but they weren’t used.

configuracion.

```
\[\[inputs.influxdb\]\]
urls = \[“http://sitioweb:8086”\]
token = “$\_TOKEN”
org = “my_org”
bucket = “recepcionData”

\[\[outputs.mqtt\]\]
servers = \[“tcp://sitioweb:1883”\]
topic = “dataInflux/prueba”
qos = 0
username = “publicador”
password = “112323434”
interval = “10s”
metric_batch_size = 1000
data_format = “influx”
```

NOTE: the server is fine.

I appreciate your help.

I need to send data that is updated in real time which I have stored in a bucket, but when configuring in `Telegrah` I get this error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> line 79: configuration specified the fields [“token” “org” “bucket”],

This message means these configuration options do not exist in the input plugin you are trying to use them with.

In this case, the influxdb input does not collect data from influxdb, rather it collects metrics from an influxdb instance only. The configuration options you are trying to use are commonly used with the influxdb outputs that send data and metrics to influxdb.